# How to put link series into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I want to make series of links:

http://imgh.us/mk1.jpg
http://imgh.us/mk2.jpg

I am using a for loop to make this series of links, and now I want to put every x-th value into `photos[i]` array. I try below code, but its not working. It seems like that there are
problems with string concentation. I know its simple but I have little knowledge of js. Can you please complete my code?

My code:

```
links =5;
var i;
var photos=new Array();
for(i=0;i<links;i++){
    photos[i] +='http:// im gh.us/mk' +i+ ' .jpg ';
}
```

Comment: Can you please write full code ?? No

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `+=` when assigning a new variable in a (empty) array.
Try this:

```
links = 5;
var photos = new Array();
for(var i  =0; i < links; i++){
    photos[i] ='http://imgh.us/mk' + i + ' .jpg';
}
```

Comment: Still not working cerbrus

Comment: @user3146565: What is not working? What _exactly_ do you need?